# Show ajax steps with messages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to know if it's possible to show ajax progress with messages from php script ?

For exemple, my backend.php got 3 steps. When I click on my button, I want :

> - to display: 'loading step 1'
> - when my backend.php move forward to step 2, display : 'loading step 2'
> - when my bakcend.php move forward to step 3, display : 'loading step 3'

Currently I only manage to do something like this with multiple ajax call, when ajax 1 is done, my alert change and I launch ajax 2....

I guess there is maybe a better way to do this ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: There are multiple options, for you the easiest might be to store the result in a file and read the file content with one ajax request. If your backend script processes, update the file, meanwhile frontend script will read the file and get the new values.

Comment: Maybe a recursive function that will call your backend.

Comment: If you want to call for each step separately, you can listen to each step end, update the ui and then make the next call and so on. If you want to do this with one call (kind of) consider to use [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications). Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39768548/863110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to do something that works ok with me.

I use server sent event (SSE) to get messages from server when I change step or get error.

Since I use only one file for the server part, I manage to use sql transaction.

And to use post data from my from, I use ajax, store these datas inside php session. If ajax return success, then I launch SSE, otherwise I stop everything.